# node_save in Drupal has issues while storing the values to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I got an issue in **node_save** in Drupal.

Below is my code:

```
function retrax_notify_create(){

    $nodeId = array();  
    $nodeObj = new stdClass(); // We create a new node object
    $nodeObj->type = "re_trax_comments_and_notes"; // Or any other content type you want
    $nodeObj->title = "Re-Trax Comments";
    $nodeObj->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; 
    node_object_prepare($nodeObj); // Set some default values.


    $nodeObj->uid = 474; 

        $nodeObj->field_userid_ref['und'][0]['value'] = '5';

        $nodeObj->field_siteid_ref['und'][0]['value'] = '6';

        $nodeObj->field_notify_count['und'][0]['value'] = 7;


    $nodeObj = node_submit($nodeObj); 
    node_save($nodeObj);
    $nodeId[nid] = $nodeObj->nid;

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($nodeObj);
    return $nodeId;         

}
```

When I run the hook menu, default values like `type`, `title`, `uid` will be stored in node table and node id will also get generated.

But the values for other three tables will not get saved for

- **field_data_field_userid_ref**
- **field_data_field_siteid_ref**
- **field_data_field_notify_count**

Database column of one of the tables is shown below

```
field_userid_ref_value  varchar(255)            Yes NULL
```

All the content types are proper but still the value is not being saved to the respective tables.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think that lines like:

```
$nodeObj->field_userid_ref['und'][0]['value'] = '5';
```

are wrong. You have parameter "value" only field type that really have a value, i.e. text field. If you have node reference or tag reference fields there should be something else. Probably:

```
$nodeObj->field_userid_ref['und'][0]['nid'] = '5';
```

for nodes, or

```
$nodeObj->field_userid_ref['und'][0]['tid'] = '5';
```

for tags, or

```
$nodeObj->field_userid_ref['und'][0]['uid'] = '5';
```

...for users, depending on what those fields are referencing...

Create some node the "common" way, from back-end, then print it and see what fields there exists.

Comment: its a text field , sorry to mention it earlier

Comment: Then create one node in that type from back-end and then print_r it or something and see exact structure and field naming.